Amcharts 5 chart in node red dashboard2 template cant get updating from msg.payload data
I get this working every 5s and it updating random data into chart.
This is node red dashboard 2 template code. Before I use dashboard 1 tempalate and all works well.
Any help?
I know I should not use HMTL tags, but this way I only get it updating?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic amCharts Example</title>
    <style>
        #chartdiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script>
am5.ready(function() {
    var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        panX: true,
        panY: true,
        wheelX: "panX",
        wheelY: "zoomX",
        pinchZoomX: true,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 1
    }));

    var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}));
    cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

    var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { 
        minGridDistance: 30, 
        minorGridEnabled: true
    });

    xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
        rotation: -90,
        centerY: am5.p50,
        centerX: am5.p100,
        paddingRight: 15
    });

    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0.3,
        categoryField: "country",
        renderer: xRenderer,
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
    }));

    var yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
        strokeOpacity: 0.1
    });

    var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0.3,
        renderer: yRenderer
    }));

    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
        name: "Series 1",
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        valueYField: "value",
        sequencedInterpolation: true,
        categoryXField: "country",
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
            labelText: "{valueY}"
        })
    }));

    series.columns.template.setAll({ cornerRadiusTL: 5, cornerRadiusTR: 5, strokeOpacity: 0 });

    // Initial Data
    var initialData = [
      { country: "USA", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
      { country: "China", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
      { country: "Japan", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
      { country: "Germany", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
      { country: "UK", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) }
    ];
    
    // Set initial data to the chart
    xAxis.data.setAll(initialData);
    series.data.setAll(initialData);
    
    // Function to update chart with new random data
    function updateChart() {
        const newData = [
            { country: "USA", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
            { country: "China", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
            { country: "Japan", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
            { country: "Germany", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },
            { country: "UK", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) }
        ];
        
        // Update the chart with new data
        xAxis.data.setAll(newData);
        series.data.setAll(newData);
        
        console.log("Chart updated with new data:", newData); // Debugging output
    }

   // Update the chart every 5 seconds
   setInterval(updateChart, 5000);

   // Optional animations on load
   series.appear(1000);
   chart.appear(1000, 100);
}); // end am5.ready()
</script>

</body>
</html>

I have tried watch,scope etc but cant get working fro msg,payload.

pretty much the exact same question and identical template was posted on the Node-RED forum here: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/amcharts-in-dashboard2/91290
I responded with a working demo for amCharts on @flowfuse/node-red-dashboard in a ui-template
Demo
GIF of amChart running in Dashbaod-2 ui-template
Template
<template>
    <div ref="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 200px" />
</template>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                chart: null,
                series: null,
                xAxis: null,
                root: null
            }
        },
        watch: {
            msg: function () {
                if (this.msg.topic === "data") {
                    this.update(this.msg.payload)
                }
            }
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            if (this.root) {
                this.root.dispose()
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // because of Dashboard 2 architecture and dynamic loading of components,
            // we need to wait until all of the modules are loaded before initialising the chart
            // TODO: find a better way to handle this!
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (window.am5 && window.am5themes_Animated && window.am5xy) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    this.init()
                }
            }, 100)
        },
        methods: {
            init: function () {
                const root = am5.Root.new(this.$refs.chartdiv)
                root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)])

                const chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
                    panX: true,
                    panY: true,
                    wheelX: "panX",
                    wheelY: "zoomX",
                    pinchZoomX: true,
                    paddingLeft: 0,
                    paddingRight: 1
                }))

                const cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}))
                cursor.lineY.set("visible", false)

                const xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
                    minGridDistance: 30,
                    minorGridEnabled: true
                })

                xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
                    rotation: -90,
                    centerY: am5.p50,
                    centerX: am5.p100,
                    paddingRight: 15
                })

                const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
                    maxDeviation: 0.3,
                    categoryField: "country",
                    renderer: xRenderer,
                    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
                }))

                const yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
                    strokeOpacity: 0.1
                })

                const yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
                    maxDeviation: 0.3,
                    renderer: yRenderer
                }))

                const series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
                    name: "Series 1",
                    xAxis: xAxis,
                    yAxis: yAxis,
                    valueYField: "value",
                    sequencedInterpolation: true,
                    categoryXField: "country",
                    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
                        labelText: "{valueY}"
                    })
                }))

                series.columns.template.setAll({ cornerRadiusTL: 5, cornerRadiusTR: 5, strokeOpacity: 0 })

                const initialData = [ ] // Initial Data (optional)
                // save refs
                this.chart = chart
                this.xAxis = xAxis
                this.series = series
                this.root = root
                this.chart.appear(1000, 100) // Optional animation on chart appearance

                // perform update
                this.update(initialData)
            },
            update: function (data) {
                if (this.root && data) {
                    // Update axes and series data with new payload
                    this.series.data.setAll(data)
                    this.xAxis.data.setAll(data)
                    this.series.appear(200) // Optional animation on update
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

Demo flow
[{"id":"1ade28cdf962acd7","type":"inject","z":"1b382109a867cbd6","name":"Every 3 sec","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"3","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"0.5","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":250,"y":140,"wires":[["fdb7ab3056e529a7"]]},{"id":"fdb7ab3056e529a7","type":"function","z":"1b382109a867cbd6","name":"random data","func":"// Create an array of data with random values or specific values\nvar data = [\n    { country: \"USA\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"China\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"Japan\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"Germany\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"UK\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"France\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"India\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"Spain\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"Netherlands\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"South Korea\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) },\n    { country: \"Canada\", value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) }\n];\n\n// Set the payload to the data array\nmsg.payload = data;\nmsg.topic = \"data\"\n\n// Return the modified message object\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"timeout":0,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":250,"y":220,"wires":[["ee2e9dd768f980e9"]]},{"id":"ee2e9dd768f980e9","type":"ui-template","z":"1b382109a867cbd6","group":"2ba35b91109753ea","page":"","ui":"","name":"DB 2 ui-template with amChart","order":1,"width":0,"height":0,"head":"","format":"<template>\n    <div ref=\"chartdiv\" style=\"width: 500px; height: 200px\" />\n</template>\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js\"></script>\n\n<script>\n    export default {\n        data() {\n            return {\n                chart: null,\n                series: null,\n                xAxis: null,\n                root: null\n            }\n        },\n        watch: {\n            msg: function () {\n                if (this.msg.topic === \"data\") {\n                    this.update(this.msg.payload, this.msg.payload)\n                }\n            }\n        },\n        beforeDestroy() {\n            if (this.root) {\n                this.root.dispose()\n            }\n        },\n        mounted() {\n            // because of Dashboard 2 architecture and dynamic loading of components,\n            // we need to wait until all of the modules are loaded before initialising the chart\n            // TODO: find a better way to handle this!\n            let interval = setInterval(() => {\n                if (window.am5 && window.am5themes_Animated && window.am5xy) {\n                    clearInterval(interval)\n                    this.init()\n                }\n            }, 100)\n        },\n        methods: {\n            init: function () {\n                const root = am5.Root.new(this.$refs.chartdiv)\n                root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)])\n\n                const chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {\n                    panX: true,\n                    panY: true,\n                    wheelX: \"panX\",\n                    wheelY: \"zoomX\",\n                    pinchZoomX: true,\n                    paddingLeft: 0,\n                    paddingRight: 1\n                }))\n\n                const cursor = chart.set(\"cursor\", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}))\n                cursor.lineY.set(\"visible\", false)\n\n                const xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {\n                    minGridDistance: 30,\n                    minorGridEnabled: true\n                })\n\n                xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({\n                    rotation: -90,\n                    centerY: am5.p50,\n                    centerX: am5.p100,\n                    paddingRight: 15\n                })\n\n                const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {\n                    maxDeviation: 0.3,\n                    categoryField: \"country\",\n                    renderer: xRenderer,\n                    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})\n                }))\n\n                const yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {\n                    strokeOpacity: 0.1\n                })\n\n                const yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {\n                    maxDeviation: 0.3,\n                    renderer: yRenderer\n                }))\n\n                const series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {\n                    name: \"Series 1\",\n                    xAxis: xAxis,\n                    yAxis: yAxis,\n                    valueYField: \"value\",\n                    sequencedInterpolation: true,\n                    categoryXField: \"country\",\n                    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {\n                        labelText: \"{valueY}\"\n                    })\n                }))\n\n                series.columns.template.setAll({ cornerRadiusTL: 5, cornerRadiusTR: 5, strokeOpacity: 0 })\n\n                const initialData = [ ] // Initial Data (optional)\n                // save refs\n                this.chart = chart\n                this.xAxis = xAxis\n                this.series = series\n                this.root = root\n                this.chart.appear(1000, 100) // Optional animation on chart appearance\n\n                // perform update\n                this.update(initialData)\n            },\n            update: function (data) {\n                if (this.root && data) {\n                    // Update axes and series data with new payload\n                    this.series.data.setAll(data)\n                    this.xAxis.data.setAll(data)\n                    this.series.appear(200) // Optional animation on update\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    }\n</script>","storeOutMessages":true,"passthru":true,"resendOnRefresh":true,"templateScope":"local","className":"","x":310,"y":300,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"2ba35b91109753ea","type":"ui-group","name":"CPT","page":"d5dfac7da5a24b2d","width":"12","height":"6","order":1,"showTitle":true,"className":"","visible":"true","disabled":"false"},{"id":"d5dfac7da5a24b2d","type":"ui-page","name":"amcharts","ui":"22ea43815413e748","path":"/amcharts","icon":"home","layout":"notebook","theme":"95e4703cc7218284","order":4,"className":"","visible":"true","disabled":"false"},{"id":"22ea43815413e748","type":"ui-base","name":"base","path":"/dashboard","includeClientData":true,"acceptsClientConfig":["ui-notification","ui-control"],"showPathInSidebar":false,"showPageTitle":true,"navigationStyle":"default","titleBarStyle":"default"},{"id":"95e4703cc7218284","type":"ui-theme","name":"Theme Name","colors":{"surface":"#ffffff","primary":"#0094ce","bgPage":"#eeeeee","groupBg":"#ffffff","groupOutline":"#cccccc"},"sizes":{"density":"default","pagePadding":"12px","groupGap":"12px","groupBorderRadius":"4px","widgetGap":"12px"}}]

Notes:
You can update the msg watch to provide different kinds of dynamic updates if required.
